# How to use windows 10 personal certificates to encrypt a file

Tags: windows-10, encryption, efs

Using Windows 10 "Manage your file encryption certificates", I have a valid certificate.  How do I use this certificate to encrypt a file?

I have tried:

1. Right click file
2. Select properties
3. Select Advanced
4. Tick Encrypt contents to secure data
5. Click OK
6. Click Apply
7. Select Encrypt the file only
8. Click OK

and I get the following error message:

[image: The error message]

1. Is this how you are supposed to encrypt a file?
2. If this is the correct approach to encrypt a file, how do I correct this issue.  As the google searches I have performed tell me to log into a domain controller to make some changes.

Note: I am running Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: EFS is ony supported by certain editions of Windows.  Are you running Windows 10 Professional?  If you are running Windows 10 Home then you cannot enable EFS, which means, you will be unable to encrypt a file on your system using the built-in Windows tools

Comment: AFAIK, If they were running Windows 10 Home, they wouldn't have this checkbox to begin with.

Comment: @Ramhound, I am running Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Considering it's long been speculated EFS has a backdoor built into, wouldn't using GPG certs be a better option, which can then also be used with a hardware key _([YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/), etc.)_, unless it's not possible to install [GPG4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct method, however, your system has a Group Policy setting that requires every EFS-encrypted file to automatically use a *second* decryption certificate (the "recovery agent" certificate).

Group Policy is *usually* deployed through a domain controller, but can also be managed locally on each system using `gpedit.msc` or `secpol.msc`. (Editions which support EFS will also generally have local policy editing tools preinstalled as well.) EFS "recovery agents" are likewise meant to be used in a corporate (domain) environment but can be enabled on standalone systems.

In your case, the configured recovery certificate does not actually match the Windows requirements for one, and as a precaution, Windows refuses to enable encryption altogether.

Comment: I strongly recomend you statisfy the Windows requirements for a certificate that is used to encrypt your files.  The requirements far exceed what is considered "secure", and there is good reasons, Windows will by default refuse to use what it considers "insecure" certificates.  *It's only slightly more effort, to generate a certificate that Windows believes to be secure, than one that isn't considered secure.*  Of course in this case, the primary reason you cannot proceed is due to a group policy, although the proper secure trusted certificate certainly should be used.

Comment: @Ramhound, any guide I can follow which explains how to get a secure certificate setup in a domain environment?